# Prevent direct access to pdf and txt tiles except from a link within the website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, whm

I need to prevent direct access to both pdf and txt files in a web directory. I have the code below in an htaccess file.  It certainly prevents direct access to the txt files but it doesnt prevent pdf files. I have tried experimenting with other extensions like mp3, etc and it works but I cannot understand why its not working with pdfs.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mywebsite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(pdf|txt) [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(pdf|txt)$ http://goaway.com/ [NC]
```

Comment: Is your `.pdf` extention low case or do you have files ending in `.PDF` ?

Comment: You are aware that this is not robust, since anyone can craft the http headers to his liking?

Comment: @Andrei, I double checked the extension and its all lowercase.  There are no files with an uppercase extension.

Comment: @arkascha I am well aware that this isnt a robust solution. What is critical currently is to sort out the issue with the pdf files.